# How to Run Script on Multiple Spreadsheet Tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp

I am writing this to understand how to run a script on multiple tabs (worksheets) in one google spreadsheet file.

1.What I am trying to do with the script:

- when specific column (here, 'status' column) been edited, add an auto timestamp in the column right after 'status' (here, 'timestamp' column).

2.Background of all tabs in the spreadsheet:

- 6 tabs in the spreadsheet.
- 'status' and 'timestamp' are not always in the same column of every tabs.
  For example, on tab Apple, 'status' is in column A and 'timestamp' is in column B. However, on tab Banana, 'status' is in column C and 'timestamp' is in column D. These cannot be changed.

3.Problem that I am having:

- Only the last script would work right after I save it.

> step1: write down code for tab Apple and save, script will work on Apple.

> step2: write down code for tab Banana (in the same script file, right after code for Apple) and save, script will work on Banana, but not working on Apple anymore.

4.What I have tried so far (not working):

- Separate code by creating multiple script files

5.Code that I am using:

```
    function onEdit(e) {
  addTimestamp(e);
}

function addTimestamp(e){
  var startRow = 2;
  var targetColumn = 24;
  var ws = "Apple";
  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws){
    
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Tokyo', 'yyyy/MM/dd');
    
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,25).setValue(time);  
    }
}

function addTimestamp(e){
  var startRow = 2;
  var targetColumn = 66;　
  var ws = "Banana"; 
  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws){
    
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Tokyo', 'yyyy/MM/dd');
    
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,67).setValue(time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Assuming that `status` is the header value of the `status` column, you could programmatically find the column index for this header using [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)) and [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex); there's no need to specify that explicitly for all your sheets (which can be feasible when there are only two sheets, but can become annoying with 6 sheets).
- You could also use [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#offset) in order to get the cell from the next column, instead of using [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)).

#### Code snippet:

Considering the previous points, your code could be greatly simplified:

```
function addTimestamp(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const statusColumn = sheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0]
                            .findIndex(header => header === "status") + 1;
  if (range.getColumn() === statusColumn && range.getRow() > 1) {
    const time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Tokyo', 'yyyy/MM/dd');
    range.offset(0,1).setValue(time);
  }
}
```

#### Update:

If you want to find the `timestamp` column by header name too, just replace this:

```
range.offset(0,1).setValue(time);
```

With this:

```
const timestampColumn = sheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0]
                             .findIndex(header => header === "timestamp") + 1;
sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), timestampColumn).setValue(time);
```

Comment: This works really well. Thank you very much! 
Hope it won't bother you too much but I have a follow up question. Is there any way to also use findIndex for 'timestamp' column? 
Just noticed that not every 'timestamp' are right after the 'status'.

Comment: @Luuu I updated my answer with the option of finding the `timestamp` column index by name, and not via `offset`. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: This works, too. Thanks for helping! I will ask another question since I found another problem while testing the sheet which is not quite related to this one. Thanks again, really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question since I just found a way out.
SUPER welcome for any other solutions!

In short, I use if function to connect codes for each tabs.

- If is tab 'Apple' then do this
- If is tab 'Banana' then do this

Code I am using are showing below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
addTimestamp(e);
}
    
  function addTimestamp(e){
    
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var col = e.range.getColumn();
    
     if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Apple" && col === 23 && row >= 2){
        
        var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Tokyo', 'yyyy/MM/dd');
        
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,24).setValue(time);}
        
        if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Banana" && col === 55 && row >= 2){
        
        var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Tokyo', 'yyyy/MM/dd');
        
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,56).setValue(time);}
```

Comment: Your example could be lightened but this is basically how I would do it